# d3.csvParse cannot read string correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a SVG to feed with CSV format data. I am using d3.js 4.13.0. I have encountered the such a problem:

my csv variable `$ajax_data` looks like this:

```
date,value
1524805006,1234
1524805012,1235
1524805018,1236
...
```

when I put the variable into the parse function:

```
d3.csvParse(ajax_data, type, function(error, data){
  console.log(data);
  if (error) throw error;
  ...
  [more processing]
  });
```

My accessor function type is defined as below:

```
function type(d){
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}

var parseDate =d3.timeParse("%s");
```

When I execute the above parse function, there is nothing in response, not even from the `console.log(data)`.

Not even if I turned the variable into a string:

```
d3.csvParse(JSON.stringify(ajax_data), type, function(error, data){
  console.log(data);
  if (error) throw error;
  ...
  [more processing]
  });
```

Still nothing in response...

Therefore I tested with the same data from `$ajax_data` and put into a csv plain file, and use the following parse method:

```
d3.csv("ajax_data.csv", type, function(error, data){
  console.log(data);
  if (error) throw error;
  ...
  [more processing]
  });
```

it worked without any problem and I have the full array:

```
[
  {date:xxxx,value:yyyy},
  {date:xxxx,value:yyyy},
  {date:xxxx,value:yyyy},
  ...
]
```

Can anyone who knows about `d3.csvParse` function tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I've seen lots of people not using the callback with `d3.csv`, which requires one, something like `var data = d3.csv(file)`... But, funnily enough, this is the first time I see the inverted problem: you're using a callback where you don't need one...

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `d3.csv`, `d3.csvParse` doesn't need a callback.

It accepts one, because this is JavaScript: a function can have more arguments than parameters or more parameters than arguments... your code doesn't throw any error because the additional argument — the callback — is just ignored.

So, it should be just:

```
var data = d3.csvParse(ajax_data, type);

console.log(data)

//more processing, etc...
```

Here is a demo with your code/data:

```js
var ajax_data = `date,value
1524805006,1234
1524805012,1235
1524805018,1236`;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%s");

var data = d3.csvParse(ajax_data, type);

console.log(data)

function type(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo, thanks for the comment and the demo. It turns out I complicated the issue, csvParse function does not need a callback as you said. Problem solved!!